# Javascript counter function onload not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying modify this fiddle so that it starts the counter onload, but when I use `onload` on the body tag it doesn't seem to be working. What did I miss? It seems the code is straight forward.
Below is the original fiddle 
[Original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/wwg8H/)

```js
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
var resume = document.getElementById("resume");
var id;
var value = "00:00";

startTimer(m, s)

function startTimer(m, s) {
  timer.textContent = m + ":" + s;
  if (s == 0) {
    if (m == 0) {
      return;
    } else if (m != 0) {
      m = m - 1;
      s = 60;
    }
  }

  s = s - 1;
  id = setTimeout(function() {
    startTimer(m, s)
  }, 1000);
}

function pauseTimer() {
  value = timer.textContent;
  clearTimeout(id);
}

function resumeTimer() {
  var t = value.split(":");

  startTimer(parseInt(t[0], 10), parseInt(t[1], 10));
}

start.addEventListener("click", function() {
  startTimer(5, 0);
}, false);

pause.addEventListener("click", pauseTimer, false);

resume.addEventListener("click", resumeTimer, false);
```

```html
<body onload="startTimer(5, 0);">

  <p id="timer">00:00</p>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="resume">Resume</button>

</body>
```

Comment: You are calling `startTimer(m, s)` in your script where `m` and `s` are `undefined`.

Comment: sorry im newbie with javascript but wouldnt onload make sure that all of the initialization has been finished before it runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `startTimer(m, s)` from your code. There `m` and `s` are not defined.

```html
<body onload="startTimer(5, 0);">

  <p id="timer">00:00</p>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="resume">Resume</button>

</body>

<script>
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  var start = document.getElementById("start");
  var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
  var resume = document.getElementById("resume");
  var id;
  var value = "00:00";



  function startTimer(m, s) {
    timer.textContent = m + ":" + s;
    if (s == 0) {
      if (m == 0) {
        return;
      } else if (m != 0) {
        m = m - 1;
        s = 60;
      }
    }

    s = s - 1;
    id = setTimeout(function() {
      startTimer(m, s)
    }, 1000);
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    value = timer.textContent;
    clearTimeout(id);
  }

  function resumeTimer() {
    var t = value.split(":");

    startTimer(parseInt(t[0], 10), parseInt(t[1], 10));
  }

  start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    startTimer(5, 0);
  }, false);

  pause.addEventListener("click", pauseTimer, false);

  resume.addEventListener("click", resumeTimer, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Just a question why did it work for the original fiddle when in mine it does not when all I did was call the start timer function onload? In the original fiddle it was not defined either and was later called thru an onclick event listener.

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks compare your code in fiddle and your question... `startTimer(m, s)` is not found in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers seem to address your actual problem, which is order of execution.

The reason your `onload="startTimer(…)"` event isn't working is that the script itself is set to execute 'onLoad', so `onload="…"` is firing before the script has run, meaning `startTimer` isn't defined yet.

By changing the JavaScript '**load type**' to "**No wrap - in < body >**" (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf4eH.jpg ), you can use the `onLoad=` attribute the way you expect:

http://jsfiddle.net/wwg8H/31/

Comment: Made a lot of sense now why my code was not running in jsfiddle and was running in SO snippet.  I did use a different approach writing my own html found that I did have a syntax error undefined variable but most importantly like you mentioned is the orer of execution.  Aside from the No wrap I needed to put the <script> ... js </script> after the <body></body> before it worked properly

Comment: yes, well "No wrap - in < body >" does exactly that; it places the script at the end of the body, so it's executed almost at the end of the document parsing phase. it's a shame that you have to think about all this while you're still trying to learn the language; that's the unfortunate nature of javascript's crufty event-driven APIs

Answer (score 0):

Move the `startTimer(m,s)` to the bottom:

```
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
var resume = document.getElementById("resume");
var id;
var value = "00:00";

function startTimer(m, s) {
    timer.textContent = m + ":" + s;
    if (s == 0) {
        if (m == 0) {
            return;
        } else if (m != 0) {
            m = m - 1;
            s = 60;
        }
    }

    s = s - 1;
    id = setTimeout(function () {
        startTimer(m, s)
    }, 1000);
}

function pauseTimer() {
    value = timer.textContent;
    clearTimeout(id);
}

function resumeTimer() {
    var t = value.split(":");

    startTimer(parseInt(t[0], 10), parseInt(t[1], 10));
}

start.addEventListener("click", function () {
    startTimer(5, 0);
}, false);

pause.addEventListener("click", pauseTimer, false);

resume.addEventListener("click", resumeTimer, false);

startTimer(5,0);  // <----------
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove startTimer(m, s)

```js
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
var resume = document.getElementById("resume");
var id;
var value = "00:00";


function startTimer(m, s) {
  timer.textContent = m + ":" + s;
  if (s == 0) {
    if (m == 0) {
      return;
    } else if (m != 0) {
      m = m - 1;
      s = 60;
    }
  }

  s = s - 1;
  id = setTimeout(function() {
    startTimer(m, s)
  }, 1000);
}

function pauseTimer() {
  value = timer.textContent;
  clearTimeout(id);
}

function resumeTimer() {
  var t = value.split(":");

  startTimer(parseInt(t[0], 10), parseInt(t[1], 10));
}

start.addEventListener("click", function() {
  startTimer(5, 0);
}, false);

pause.addEventListener("click", pauseTimer, false);

resume.addEventListener("click", resumeTimer, false);
```

```html
<body onload="startTimer(5, 0);">

  <p id="timer">00:00</p>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
  <button id="resume">Resume</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As browser renders HTML page from top to bottom, Your Javascript will get rendered after the body contents are loaded. So, Body - Onload event can't call your startTimer method as it is not available yet in the page.

You can move your startTimer(5,0) call to the bottom of the script.